# Webservice in Monotouch returns XML instead of JSON

Tags: xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest

I trying to get JSON data through a HttpWebRequest object using Monotouch. It works fine in the IPhone Simulator and I get JSON back. But when I run the application in the device, I always get XML back instead of JSON when the web service is invoked..

Is there any specific configuration parameters I would have to set to get the results as JSON, when running from the IPhone ? I am running this on IPhone 5 , ios 6..

Here is my code..

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format (@"{0}/GetActiveProductCountAfterID/filter?minID={1}",baseUrl, lastProductNumberInDatabase));
Logger.Debug("Request URL is: " + request.RequestUri);
request.ContentType = @"application/json";  
request.Method = "GET";
try{
     using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
     {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
           Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
........
```

When I run in the simulator, I get content as an integer..for example: 3456

But when I run it from the IPhone, I get

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">3456</int>
```

Comment: If you can share (privately) the URL to your service please fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com If it's internal then a network trace (e.g. done with Wireshark) from both the simulator and the device (would need to be done server side) might help us see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it by setting the server side web service to have json as the default web service. For those of you who might run into the same issue, here is what I had to do to have Json as the default format (in the web.config file on the .Net WCF in the server)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"   defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```